# Removing multiple columns in table within a database. (rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am having trouble removing multiple columns in my local database.

My table name is 'customers' and within that table the two columns I am trying to remove are 'phone' and 'fax'

I've been trying something along the lines of this

```
class CustomerCleanup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change_table(:customers) do |t|
      t.remove :fax, :phone
    end
  end
end
```

but I continue to get a syntax error stating  'unexpected tSYMBEG expecting ')'

I've looked at the examples in [Here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_table)....and I've tried this as well only to get the same error

```
class CustomerCleanup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change_table(:customers) do |t|
      t.remove :fax
      t.remove :phone
    end
  end
end
```

Would anyone know what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of Rails are you using?

Comment: `remove_column :myTable, :col1`

Comment: @Jerrod i'm using 2.1.6

Comment: @Drew would I have to go `remove_column :myTable, :col1, :col2`? I've more than one thing to remove

Comment: probably why @Jerrod asked the version. I believe Rails 4 changed

Comment: @Drew I just realized i gave you my ruby version. My rails version is 4.1.12. (sorry)

Comment: @kdweber89 I was thinking that you are using Rails 2.1.6 so I had to update my answer :p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
def change
  remove_column :customers, :fax
  remove_column :customers, :phone
end
```

---

In case you are using rails version lower than 3.x

```
def self.up
 remove_column :customers, :fax
 remove_column :customers, :phone
end

def self.down
  # do something on rollback here or just do nothing
end
```

Comment: Do you know if there is an actual way to loop through them? I'm asking because I actually like 6 things to remove.

Comment: you mean: `[:fax, :phone, :sth].each { |column| remove_column :customers, column }` ?

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old question and has a marked answer, but no one addressed your actual syntax error.  You are combining your method definition with your change_table call.  The correct code should be:

```
class CustomerCleanup < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table(:customers) do |t|
      t.remove :fax
      t.remove :phone
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 11):

You can remove multiple columns in a single statement with the [`remove_columns` method](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/remove_columns)

```
def up
  remove_columns :customers, :fax, :phone
end
```

But you'll have to define a separate `down` method if you want to be able to roll back.

Comment: While this works perfectly fine, it generates multiple SQL statements (at least that's what it does in Rails 5.2.5). This can be problematic when altering really large tables; a single SQL statement with multiple `drop column` clauses would be way more efficient. In order to generate a single SQL statement, you can use a `change_table` block as explained in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39615281/4092455).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to remove column's from any table by running a migration then try this

```
rails g migration remove_columns_from_table_name field_name:datatype field_name:datatype
```

replace **table_name** with the table from which you want to delete the columns and **field_name:data_type** with the columns and the datatype of columns you want to remove.

The migration file will look like this

```
class RemoveColumnsFromTableName < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    remove_column :table_name, :field_name, :data_type
    remove_column :table_name, :field_name, :data_type
  end
end
```

and then run the migration

```
rake db:migrate
```

And you can also delete the columns directly from your `rails console` by doing something like this

```
ActiveRecord::Migration.remove_column :table_name, :column_name
```